# How to get name of local machine in server in PHP?

Tags: php

when i am using the following PHP code i am getting the name of my PC in local server.

```
<?php
echo gethostbyaddr($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
?>
```

im getting the result as ELIZABETH-PC in local server but i am not getting that name when running in main server?How can i get that?is it possible?

Comment: This is not an issue within php. It is a question of how your network resolves ip addresses to host names.

Comment: The client machine name is not sent in the HTTP protocol, there's no way for the server to know it. It only knows the IP. You need to configure the reverse DNS on your network to translate that to the hostname you want.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
<?php

echo gethostname(); 

echo php_uname('n'); // for vesrions older than 5.3
?>
```

Comment: Here also i am not getting my PC name.